# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'elements') at VueComponent.mounted vue-stripe

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, stripe-payments

i've a vue app which uses stripe as payment but each time i refresh i get
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'elements')

this the error i get in my console

```
Error in mounted hook: "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'elements')"
```

this is my script tag on how i call my stripe payment

```
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      error: "",
      stripe: null,
      card: null
    };
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters([
      "getCart",
     
    ])
  },
  mounted() {
    this.stripe = Stripe("pk_test_51KGqWkHC");
    let elements = this.stripe.elements();
    this.card = elements.create("card");
    this.card.mount(this.$refs.card);
  },
  methods: {
    async onPurchase() {
      try {
        let token = stripe.createToken(this.card);
        let response = axios.post("http://localhost:5000/api/pay", {
          token: token,
          totalPrice: this.getCartTotalPriceWithShipping,
          cart: this.getCart,
          estimatedDelivery: this.getEstimatedDelivery
        });
        if (response.success) {
          // Do something like redirecting to the home page
          this.$store.commit("clearCart");
          this.$router.push("/");
        }
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
    },
  
  }
};
</script>
```

I use this in my nuxt js project and it works fine,
please what i'm i doing wrong in vue

Answer (score 0):

```
this.stripe.elements();
```

returns undefined, probably this is not working:

```
Stripe("pk_test_51KGqWkHC");
```

check that the initialization string you are using is correct.

Otherwise, check the docs.

Answer (score 0):

if its `undefined`, you can handle this error:

```js
  mounted() {
    this.stripe = Stripe("pk_test_51KGqWkHC");
    if(this.stripe.elements) {
       let elements = this.stripe.elements();
       this.card = elements.create("card");
       this.card.mount(this.$refs.card);
    }
  },
```

But seeing your whole code, you have some inconsistencies:

Im not sure how you're supposed to access to `Stripe()`, if you don't have imported it. Maybe it's a module?
`Stripe("pk_test_51KGqWkHC")` -> `this.$stripe("pk_test_51KGqWkHC")`

Then in `let token = stripe.createToken(this.card);`
stripe doesn't exists in `async onPurchase()`, so how do you have access to it?
This should be `this.stripe.createToken(this.card)` or `this.$stripe.createToken(this.card)` if Stripe is injected on Vue.